# Laravel Unit Test

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

RefreshDatabase dont clean up database after tetsing

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication, RefreshDatabase;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a transaction then, not refreshdatabase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you phpunit.xml file add the following code inside

<phpunit>

<!--insert the configuration here-->

</phpunit>

Code to insert

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="API_DEBUG" value="false"/>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="512M" />
    <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
</php>
```

and run the test